# Mobile Friendly Navigation

Tags: mobile, navigation

How do I create a mobile friendly navigation bar?

### This is my code

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <a href="http://www.startinpoint.com/"><img src="images/logo.jpg" class="logo span12 pull-left" height="45"></a>
            <li>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</li>
            <li><a href="adminhome.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">VIEW <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="viewleavetransaction.html">LEAVE TRANSACTION</a></li>
                    <li><a href="viewleavesummary.html">LEAVE SUMMARY</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="generatemedicalclaim.html">GENERATE MEDICAL CLAIM</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown active">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">SETTINGS <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="addoreditemployee.html">EMPLOYEE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="addoreditpublicholiday.html">PUBLIC HOLIDAY</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="addoreditannualleave.html">ANNUAL LEAVE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="addoreditoffinlieu.html">OFF-IN-LIEU</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="pull-right"><a href="index.html">LOGOUT</a></li>
            <li class="siptext pull-right"><strong>SIP Leave Application</strong></li>
    </ul>
```

What do I need to add more?

asdhcsjkfwalfkjdsbfdzjvgfdkjvgf

Answer (score -1):

You have to include bootstrap js file and add `.navbar-collapse` class to parent div of that `ul`.

Check that page for samples and all options. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: parent divs and their classes are important for that function. please update your question and add parent divs to sample code. if you have proper parent divs, `.navbar-collapse` class is enough to create a section which will be collapsed in mobile devices.